# XUbuntu won't boot

Tags: xubuntu, boot-failure

I can't properly boot my XUbuntu desktop. It just hangs on the console without any visible errors. The only way i can boot it properly is choosing "recovery mode" in GRUB and then selecting "continue booting" in recovery menu. It's really annoying.

I provide some logs here:
http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/mQ%2FzdWvVcrjB3dz4vVqjsw

Please advise! If you need some additional information i will be glad to provide it. Any hints and support will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to update XUbuntu to current stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In the console:
**`sudo fdisk -l`**
Then you can see the partitions you have. The partition marked with * is the boot partition.
Assume this is /dev/sda1, type the following command:
**`fsck /dev/sda1`**
This will check and repair that partition. Maybe this helps

Comment: Looks like i need to do it when partition is not mounted. Thanks, i will try this later, but i don't think it will really help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you of all. You are saying Xubuntu only boots normally after doing that or Xubuntu only boots in recovery mode? If only works in recovery mode, maybe it is a xorg problem. Try this

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And reboot. That should help if it is a xorg problem.

Comment: My XUbuntu boots only in recovery mode. I think the problem is related to graphical stack (X-Server, Desktop Manager, Video Drivers or smth), but i can't pinpoint it correctly.